# AngularJS checkboxes for quiz

Tags: angularjs

i'm new to angular, stuck with, what i hope is a rather easy problem.

I Have a question and several answers. There might be 1-3 correct answers.
Answers can be selected by checkbox. In the value field i save if the answers is correct (true) or wrong (false). I was hopping that i can simply get things work by getting ng-valid and ng-invalid.
E.g. The answers is wrong, when clicked on the checkbox for this answer the anwswer text should be red (or sth.). When deselecting it should go back to normal. Same with correct answers.

That's how i currently try to do it:

```
<label ng-repeat="a in q.answers"><input type="checkbox" value="{{ a.correct }}" ng-pattern="true" ng-model="field.value"> {{ a.title }}</label>
```

So if the value is true it should match the pattern 'true'. Does not working, ng-pattern does not seem to have any effect.
Anyone know how to solve this.
If it's more sophisticated than i thought i might be doing the check with jquery. But i want to try pure angular first.

PS: i tried to find a answer to this, but i couldn't find anything that suits my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding onto the class suggestion from Jared Reeves, here is one way that you might implement the checkbox answers:

```html
<label ng-repeat="answer in question.answers" ng-class="{'invalid': answer.checked && !answer.correct, 'valid': answer.checked && answer.correct}">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-change="select(field, answer)" ng-model="answer.checked"> {{answer.title}}
</label>
Selected answer: {{field.value}}
```

```js
// inside the controller

$scope.field = {
  value: null
};

$scope.question = {
  answers: [
    {title: "A (incorrect)", correct: false},
    {title: "B (incorrect)", correct: false},
    {title: "C (correct)",   correct: true},
    {title: "D (incorrect)", correct: false}
  ]
};

$scope.select = function(field, answer) {
  if (answer.checked) {
    field.value = answer;
  } else {
    field.value = null;
  }
};
```

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qa2VrukMD61y8Jv4iKjx?p=preview